# How to provide import aliases in eslint new flat config?

Tags: webpack, eslint

How do you provide a list of aliases in the new flat `eslint` config? I have tried the following:

```
export default [
  ...
  {
    settings: {
      "import/resolver": {
        alias: {
          extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.tsx'],
          map: [
            ['components', './packages/some-package/src/components']
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  }
  ...
];
```

Also tried with `eslint-import-resolver-webpack` since I am using `webpack`

```
"import/resolver": {
  webpack: {
    config: './packages/some-package/webpack.config.dev.js'
  }
}
```

It still highlights anything with `import/no-unresolved`